# error dependency is not satisfiable: libmonosystemruntime2.0cil

Tags: package-management, vpn

so I downloaded AirVPN linux_64_bit.deb package but i keep getting this error:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPqOL.png)

I'm using galliumos on a Toshiba Chromebook (2015). any advice is appreciated, i just want a VPN, so any other advice as to how to do that on this OS will help me out tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

In the 16.04 repos, the package is called `libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil`. It should cover 2.0.